# RN fs: Native module cannot be null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I work on expo, I installed `react-native-fs`  and I have this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

And my code:

```
import fs from 'react-native-fs';

;(async ()=>{
  let data = await fs.readFile('./data/user/access.json', 'utf8');

  let a = JSON.parse(data);
  
  a.push({
    test: 10,
    other: true,
    string: 'hello world',
  });
  
  let json = JSON.stringify(a);
  
  fs.writeFile('./data/user/access.json', json, 'utf8');
})();
```

Comment: here is the same problem you can check and see if its helpful.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110388/invariant-violation-native-module-cannot-be-null-error-only-showing-up-on-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work with a managed project. You’ll need to use the Bare workflow if using react-native-fs is a necessity for you.

Cheers,