# Can a project built with React native CLI be run with expo CLI?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a project built with react native CLI, now I want to run the same project using expo. Can this be possible? if yes any link to the procedure for configuration.

earlier: I tried using expo :

I created a new expo project with the same name as the old project.

Then transferred all the folders containing my component to the new expo project.
Also transferred the package.json file to it. Then run yarn install to install all packages.
But encountering a lot of errors.

please would appreciate if any link to the procedure on how this is done if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the errors, by removing all packages that aren't supported by Expo and by using expo equivalents for some of the old packages. The rest of the packages which didn't have expo documented in them, I removed from package.json. And commented out import and functions using those packages.

you can check if a package supports expo by searching in the package's GitHub documentation.

Another way to solve this is to create a new expo project and slowly add files.

It worked. Thanks to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266246/7689878